# UITableView 2 Customized Cells

Tags: ios

I am trying to make a `UITableview` like Simple Bank.

Example:

March 3, 2014
Mike
Aaron
March 4, 2014
Beth

The date will be one cell and the name would be another cell. If names are associated to the same date, the date would only be shown once.
I know how to create one custom cell. Any help on how to accomplish this would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you need to break thus into sections

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any good links or advice on how sections work? Thanks

Comment: Abizen is right, make use of sections, use date as section headers and names as index List, For better understanding read this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a grouped table view. Use custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews` for the dates.